# Star of David with cross inside

Tags: christianity

I will be attending a funeral of my sister in law (Christian) and brother in law (Jewish).  I would like to wear a necklace with Star of David with a cross inside to the service.

Am I risking offending anyone by that?  That is the last thing I would want to do! ! !

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Most Jewish people would find this outrageously offensive as it has overtures of replacement theology.

Comment: Point taken.  Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it’s extremely offensive.

Comment: I wish to show solidarity and acceptance of my relatives who have passed, and had differing beliefs.  So how do I show that?

Comment: @Gracie By being a good person. Why focus on your relatives’ religion? Why not focus on the things they accomplished in life, things they liked when they were alive, memories you have with them, etc.

Comment: Point taken.  Furthermore, I have been a good person.  By simply being present at their service will have to suffice, since they are my former husband's relatives.

Comment: I know you mean well, but ... religion is one of those things where good fences make good neighbors. Trying to combine or equate them doesn't work well. You are you, a good person, coming to pay respects for various people, each of whom had their own religion. That's the way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your grace toward my intentions.  This has been truly helpful.